# Can I compare models from linear regression and nonlinear regression using RMSE?

Tags: r, regression

I am comparing multiple published equation forms, refit with independent data.  I'm trying to be true to the original authors' methods as much as possible. Therefore, I have 3 linear equations (fit in R using lm()), two of which use transformed Y-variables, and one equation fit using nonlinear regression (fit in R using the gnls() function).

In all instances cases I'm weighting the residual variance structure using the inverse of one of the predictors to account for observed heteroskedasticity.

I have been evaluating the models using R2, and RMSE- using back-transformed data for the two models with transformations.

I've calculated RMSE "by hand" using the following equation:

```
 RMSE<-sqrt(sum(residuals(Equation)^2)/length(residuals(Equation))-2))
```

Should I use similar code to calculate RMSE for the linear and nonlinear regression models?  Is the metric still a valid statistic for comparison, or am I missing some important assumption?

Edited: I initially stated that I was also comparing models using AIC; I later recalled that AIC would not be appropriate if the Y-variables were transformed because the models would be estimating different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- RMSE is certainly appropriate also for nonlinear models
- However, the RMSE expressions I know actually calculate the *mean*, so no `-2` (looks like d.f. for linear model? - d.f. for nonlinear models would be different!)
- In general, I'd not use the residuals for calculating RMSE but rather use independent test cases to avoid an optimistic bias.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation),

> RMSE is a frequently used measure of the differences between values
>   predicted by a model or an estimator and the values actually observed.

Further,

> RMSE is a good measure of accuracy, but only to compare forecasting
>   errors of different models for a particular variable and not between
>   variables, as it is scale-dependent.

Clearly, you can use RMSE for comparing the forecast error between different models (linear or nonlinear), as long as you are comparing models for a particular variable. I don't see any assumptions to consider.